# SQL Server 2014 SP1 extract with progress bar using command line arguments

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

`SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe /u /x:LocationToExtract` does not show progress bar when executed from my `VB6` application, whereas if I run the same command from command prompt, I'm getting the progress bar.

```
sample syntax: "E:\SQL 2014 Express x64\SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe /u /x:"C:\SQLEXPRWT""
```

Even in `SQL Server 2014 SP1` I'm not getting the progress bar while extracting.

May I know how to show progress bar while extracting from `VB6` code?

Comment: May be due to permission issues ?

Comment: Maybe process monitor will tell you what goes wrong: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645